# DOM or DOT? What is more precise term?

Tags: html

Document Object Mobel (DOM) is tree of objects which is generated after page load to access.
I wonder why it is called DOM but not Document Object Tree (DOT)?
Isn't DOT more suitable term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found answer in w3. The reason that its Document Object Model is,

> In the DOM, documents have a logical structure which is very much like a tree; to be more precise, which is like a "forest" or "grove", which can contain more than one tree. Each document contains zero or one doctype nodes, one root element node, and zero or more comments or processing instructions; the root element serves as the root of the element tree for the document. However, the DOM does not specify that documents must be implemented as a tree or a grove, nor does it specify how the relationships among objects be implemented. The DOM is a logical model that may be implemented in any convenient manner. In this specification, we use the term structure model to describe the tree-like representation of a document. We also use the term "tree" when referring to the arrangement of those information items which can be reached by using "tree-walking" methods; (this does not include attributes). One important property of DOM structure models is structural isomorphism: if any two Document Object Model implementations are used to create a representation of the same document, they will create the same structure model, in accordance with the XML Information Set [Infoset].
>
> Note: There may be some variations depending on the parser being used to build the DOM. For instance, the DOM may not contain whitespaces in element content if the parser discards them.
>
> The name "Document Object Model" was chosen because it is an "object model" in the traditional object oriented design sense: documents are modeled using objects, and the model encompasses not only the structure of a document, but also the behavior of a document and the objects of which it is composed. In other words, the nodes in the above diagram do not represent a data structure, they represent objects, which have functions and identity.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html

Comment: Apologies for not adding source URL where I got the answer. Please read the reference at http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html